# return value from Kotlin async Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, coroutine

I want to return value from this function which gets data from local database:

```
fun getAllTodo() :  LiveData<List<TodoModel>>{

   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val data = async { getTodoFromDB() }
        data.await()
    }
}

suspend fun getTodoFromDB(): LiveData<List<TodoModel>> {
    return database.getAll()
}
```

P.S: I am new to Coroutine, might have done something silly. Looking forward for Android community help

Answer (score 0):

A value can't be returned from launched coroutine. If `getTodoFromDB()` returns `LiveData` object and is not `suspend`, just try to call it without launching a coroutine:

```
fun getAllTodo(): LiveData<List<TodoModel>> = getTodoFromDB()
```

If `getTodoFromDB()` is `suspend` you can use [`liveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) builder function:

```
val allTodo:  LiveData<List<TodoModel>> = liveData {
   emitSource(getTodoFromDB())
}
```